# InnerText from event.target event not returning the text from target

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access only the text from an event.target but using innerText does not return the text. It returns undefined or blank.

Here's what I've tried.

```
 function init(){
            document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect); //'change' refers to when the file changes, 2nd argument calls function
        }

        function handleFileSelect(event){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (evt)=>{
                console.log(evt.target.result);
                // console.log(evt.target.result.innerText);
                document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = evt.target.result;
            };
            reader.onerror = ()=>{
                console.log("ERROR READING FILE");
            };
            reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]); //takes only the first element (file) uploaded

        }

        window.onload = init; //when everything loads
```

I have also tried

```
console.log(evt.target.innerText)
```

But still does not work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: what is the file type ? and is the file contains JSON object has property called **innerText** ?

Comment: file type is HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery Verison**

```js
function getTextFromHTML(htmlText) {
  var temp = $('<div>');
  var text = temp.html(htmlText).text();
  temp.remove();
  return text;
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);
}

function handleFileSelect(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (evt) => {
    var htmlText = evt.target.result;
    document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = getTextFromHTML(htmlText);
  };
  reader.onerror = () => {
    console.log("ERROR READING FILE");
  };
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />

<div id="fileContent"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Pure JavaScript Version**

```js
function getTextFromHTML(htmlText) {
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  var html = temp.innerHTML = htmlText;
  var text = temp.textContent;

  return text;
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);
}

function handleFileSelect(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (evt) => {
    var htmlText = evt.target.result;
    document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = getTextFromHTML(htmlText);
  };
  reader.onerror = () => {
    console.log("ERROR READING FILE");
  };
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />

<div id="fileContent"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way of replacing ' var temp = $('<div>');' with pure javascript?

Comment: is there a way of getting only the body tag of the targeted file?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472335/147525 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857261/1475257

Answer (score 0):

To get the result from a `FileReader` you should just use `reader.result`.

Like so (this is your code, working completely fine):

```js
function init(){
    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect); //'change' refers to when the file changes, 2nd argument calls function
}

function handleFileSelect(event){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt)=>{
        document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.onerror = ()=>{
        console.log("ERROR READING FILE");
    };
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<div id="fileContent">file content</div>
```

If this doesn't work as intended on your end, check here if your browser supports the FileReader API: https://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: does reader.result return only text? I have run the snippet and it returns the inner HTML of the file.

Comment: HTML files are text files, it will return the text, which is HTML code.